# Read SharedPreferences when you haven't set the name of the file

Tags: android, preference, sharedpreferences

When you createa a PreferenceScreen on Android, your application creates a default SharedPreferences file for the settings.
I want to read this name, or get a reference without specifing the name.

Currently I use:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed=prefs.edit();
```

But this returns another copy of the preference. When I checked the folder in /data/data/myapk/shared_prefs

I see two files, one named prefs.xml and the other is my [package name]_preferences.xml (this was created by the PreferenceActivity);

How do I get an instance of the shared preference with the usage of the default file name, so I should not mention a name for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you want [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)).