# Keeping custom SharedPreferences and preferences from prefs.xml in the same place

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using this method to get `SharedPreferences` that are programatically set:

```
public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(final Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName()
            + "_preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
}
```

I'm also using `prefs.xml` in my `PreferenceActivity` like that:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
```

I would like to **store all of the apps preferences in the same place** (preferably: `context.getPackageName() + "_preferences")` ), how do I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Also I think `context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);` will return the default shared prefs in an undocumented manner

Comment: I am setting a listener and would like to compare a value from the first set of shared preferences and from the second set (i.e.. based on `prefs.xml`). Should I just store all of my preferences in the default shared prefs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name you chose for your shared preferences file is the name of the default shared preferences file - and this will end up being bad. The doc for preference fragment [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)

> These preferences will automatically save to SharedPreferences as the user interacts with them. To retrieve an instance of SharedPreferences that the preference hierarchy in this activity will use, call getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context) with a context in the same package as this activity.

The xml you load the preferences from is not related to the xml they are saved.

So use `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, *do not mess with filenames of shared preferences*, read the java doc quoted (applies to the PreferenceActivity more or less) and have a look at :

- [Difference between getDefaultSharedPreferences and getSharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences)
- [Where are shared preferences stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146106/where-are-shared-preferences-stored)
- [How do I get the SharedPreferences from a PreferenceActivity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android)
- [Read SharedPreferences when you haven't set the name of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403228/read-sharedpreferences-when-you-havent-set-the-name-of-the-file)